# Как работать с MailRu API?

Tags: php, api, key, mail.ru

Хотелось бы через `mail.getUnreadCount` получать количество непрочитаных сообщений для нотификатора. Но их документация расписана слабо, а в интернете я практически не нашел информации. Можете подсказать как получить все коды для такого запроса?

```
http://www.appsmail.ru/platform/api?method=mail.getUnreadCount&
app_id=123456&session_key=551fd0e4779e35859dfccd03397dc8a0&
sig=95a393ed7639184a52f7a17b6771a925
```

`app_id` я могу получить, а вот `session_key` и `sig` я не понимаю как получить. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: http://api.mail.ru/docs/guides/social-apps/

Comment: есть ответ?.....